# macOS Monterey failing to start vagrant box?

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a Vagrant box with Virtual Box setup.

I just updated my macOS version Monterey (12.0.1) and I am getting following error when I try to `vagrant up` my box.

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

Also, I tried to run this command `VBoxManage hostonlyif create` which is giving below output:

```
0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

I tried following:

1. Given all required permissions from Security preferences and also allowed full disk access to VirtualBox and Terminal apps.
2. Also tried upgrading to latest vagrant and virtual box.
3. Re-installed both vagrant and virtualbox

But none of the above worked yet, anyone please help!

Answer (score 2):

### Re-install whatever version of VirtualBox you are using to get the host-only adapter in place again.

The other answers here are focusing on other issue — where VirtualBox is failing to start in `headless` mode [as described in this other question](https://superuser.com/q/1683747/167207) — but your error is clearly different and something I ran into myself. Note this error you are getting:

```
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
```

I had this error as well. And the only way I solved it is to reboot my MacBook, and then reinstall VirtualBox again.

I believe this happens when one updates VirtualBox, and then that “System Preferences” prompt comes up. I believe it stops the process of installing the host-only adapter so you basically have to reboot and reinstall VirtualBox again.

To confirm the host-only adapter is indeed in place, launch the VirtualBox GUI application and then click on “Tools” which is the top menu item on the left; you should see a `vboxnet0` adapter as shown in the screenshot below.

That `vboxnet0` is the host-only adapter. And if it is there, you should be able to do a `vagrant up` and your machine should start. But then again — as said at the outset — there is another issue with Vagrant and VirtualBox [that is addressed in that other SuperUser thread](https://superuser.com/q/1683747/167207).

[image: VirtualBox “Tools” screenshot.]

Answer (score -1):

Temporary workaround is here -> https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12557

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.